# 'who' command has blank output when using SSH

Tags: ssh, login, authentication

I have an Ubuntu virtual machine which I access via SSH. When I execute the `who` command I get nothing. Moreover I get this output when executing `systemctl --user`:

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

When executing `systemctl status dbus` I get everything normal except for this line:

```
[system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

The output before log is:

```
dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-01-03 14:12:08 UTC; 20h ago
 Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
Main PID: 1368 (dbus-daemon)
 Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
 CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service
       └─1368 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
```

The output of `systemctl status systemd-logind` is:

```
systemd-logind.service - Login Service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service; 
static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-01-04 11:25:15 UTC; 1h 44min ago
Docs: man:systemd-logind.service(8)
       man:logind.conf(5)
       https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind
       https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
 Process: 24112 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-logind (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 24112 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Status: "Shutting down..."
```

Any suggestion about what is going on?

Comment: So now we've isolated the problem to the `logind` service failing - so far so good.

Comment: Ok but why does `logind` fail?, I tried everything to trace the issue with no luck

Comment: Yeah, to that I haven't got a clue.. 

Comment: Is there any additional information in the journal (ex. `journalctl -xe -u systemd-logind.service`)?

Comment: No the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved - the directory `/var/run` should be symlink to `/run`, but for an unknown reason it was not.

Please refer to:
[Is my /var directory OK, since /var/run isn't a symlink?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450354/is-my-var-directory-ok)