# Is my /var directory OK, since /var/run isn't a symlink?

Tags: filesystem, symbolic-link, fhs

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. When I run:

```
ls -la /var
```

I get the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root   4096 Jan  2 15:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root   4096 Jan 15 06:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root   4096 Jan  6 06:15 cache
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   4096 Jan 12 06:41 crash
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root   4096 Jan  4 11:06 Lib
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     11 Dec 27 07:22 lock -> ../run/lock
drwxrwxr-x  8 root syslog 4096 Jan 10 06:06 log
drwx------  6 root root   4096 Jan 15 06:03 run
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Jan  3 14:54 snap
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Dec 27 07:22 spool
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root   4096 Jan 15 06:03 tmp
```

AFAIK `/var/run` should be symlink to `/run`. I have some problems in my system as described in ['who' command has blank output when using SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1448542/who-command-has-blank-output-when-using-ssh), so is it because `/var/run` is not a symlink?
Can I safely remove it and replace it with a symlink?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right that `/var/run` is normally a symlink.

However, if `/var/run` does not contain any files, it should be safe to replace with a symlink. If there are files, you should move them to `/run` first.

When the directory `/var/run` is empty, you can replace with a symlink like this:

```
$ rmdir /var/run
$ ln -s /run /var/run
```

Referring to your [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1448542/who-command-has-blank-output-when-using-ssh), I guess this could be the cause of failure, since `/run` contains the socket `/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`.

Comment: Actually it was the problem, after removing /var/run and add the link the service is back to life again thank you very much

Comment: Sounds good. 

Comment: On my Arch Linux system, `/var/run` is a symlink to `../run`, which presumably makes it work better if looking at a chroot or container filesystem from outside that container.  So I'd recommend `ln -s ../run /var/run`, unless Ubuntu normally uses a different symlink.

Comment: You're probably right. But the default Ubuntu symlink points to just `/run` (and its size is 4 bytes).

Answer (score 5):

You should **never** unlink `/var/run` from `/run` or use it for any other purpose ... The sole purpose that `/var/run` existed **long time ago** was to hold system information data describing the system since it was booted ... This functionality has been moved to `/run` in modern systems ... However, [`/var/run`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s13.html) still exists to ensure compatibility with systems and software that are still using the old specification.

Your [linked other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1448542/968501) is a living example of such software ... The [`who`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/who.1.html) command still uses `/var/run` as stated in its manual:

> If FILE is not specified, use **/var/run/utmp**.

and an `strace` on Ubuntu 22.04 confirms that:

```bash
strace -e openat who
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 # <-- This one
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
ubuntu   :0           2023-01-12 19:48 (:0)
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Thanks for some additional background information!

Comment: Actually it's more like `/var/run` is the broad-scoped name of the endpoint. `/run` only exists at all if it's a ramdrive. If you don't have a ramdrive (maybe because your memory supply is puny); it's going to be `/var/run` as a directory cleared at boot.

Comment: @Joshua Actually, it's not really about what I or you think of it :-) ... This is how it is and should be since [FHS(*Filesystem Hierarchy Standard*) V. 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)